# Voxeet Cordova - CFBundleIdentifier Collision

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, cordova-plugins, bundle-identifier

I was able to add the plugin upgrading **xcode** version to **13**.
I test my app and everything is working but then I try to archive the `.ipa` and upload it to the appStore and I face with this error:

> CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the
> CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.onevcat.Kingfisher' under the iOS
> application 'WorkoutMinister.app'. With error code
> STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90685 for id
> c3d0e0ae-8bce-4e4f-a335-2244043d4a3d

I looked for information about it and I know that is caused by embedded framework reference inside the `xcframwork` build but i don't know how to change this.